# How can I dispatch SyntheticEvent events?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a component which won't have any input/select element but I want it to behave like one, dispatching the same events a React input does, expecting to have something like this working:

```
<div onChange={this.onChange}>
    <MyComponent/>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>
```

In that example, both, input and MyComponent should reach the this.onChange listener.

I know how to dispatch real DOM events, but that's not making it to the onChange listener, only to a real addEventListener on the DOM:

```
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('change', true, false);

this.getDOMNode().dispatchEvent(event);
```

Maybe the answer is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8614dd3cf9f831bfe4ce0c513ff4caf538b69b22/src/renderers/dom/client/wrappers/ReactDOMInput.js) (or [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/8614dd3cf9f831bfe4ce0c513ff4caf538b69b22/src/renderers/dom/client/eventPlugins/ChangeEventPlugin.js#L73-L93)?), but I'm still struggling with this.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @limelights for preparing a playground:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/a8wgh5wk/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why React event handler is not called on dispatchEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065010/why-react-event-handler-is-not-called-on-dispatchevent)

Comment: look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065010/why-react-event-handler-is-not-called-on-dispatchevent/45356934#45356934

Answer (score 0):

The `onChange` event through React is only available for form controls which means that you'll never get them to register as a handler on a DIV tag.