# Why React event handler is not called on dispatchEvent?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-testutils

Consider the following input element in a React component:

```
<input onChange={() => console.log('onChange')} ... />
```

While testing the React component, I'm emulating user changing the input value:

```
input.value = newValue;
TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
```

This causes `'onChange'` to be logged, as expected.

However, when the `'change'` event is dispatched directly (I'm using jsdom):

```
input.value = newValue;
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

the `onChange` handler is not called.

Why?

My motivation to use `dispatchEvent` rather than `TestUtils.Simulate` is because `TestUtils.Simulate` doesn't support event bubbling and my component's behavior relies on that. I wonder whether there is a way to test events without `TestUtils.Simulate`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

React uses its own events system with `SyntheticEvents` (prevents browser incompatabilities and gives react more control of events).

Using `TestUtils` correctly creates such a event which will trigger your `onChange` listener.

The `dispatchEvent` function on the other hand will create a "native" browser event. But the event handler you have is managed by react and therefore only reacts (badumts) to reacts `SyntheticEvents`.

You can read up on react events here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Answer (score 19):

One way to do it without `ReactTestUtils.Simulate`:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://unpkg.com/react-trigger-change/dist/react-trigger-change.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
input.value = value;
reactTriggerChange(input);
```

Look at the [source of react-trigger-change](https://github.com/vitalyq/react-trigger-change/blob/master/lib/change.js#L88) to just cherry-pick what's needed. Example snippet:

```
if (nodeName === 'select' ||
    (nodeName === 'input' && type === 'file')) {
    // IE9-IE11, non-IE
    // Dispatch change.
    event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent('change', true, false);
    node.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
```

- https://github.com/vitalyq/react-trigger-change
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3249#issuecomment-292919084

Comment: Not enough info, here. What is `value`? If I want to click a button, should that be added to `const input` or `const input.value`? And so I tried just setting it to `const input`, and got that `reactTriggerChange is undefined`, so I added an Import statement.  Then got `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.  Plus I have a ton of linting errors I would have to clean up to use this package :( .

Comment: @vapcguy added more description

Comment: @rofrol Thanks-I pulled the last 3 lines out to use them in an event handler I made for a button to click another button. I assign `node`: `const node = document.getElementsByClassName("close");` My target button has `class="close"` & it's the only element on the page with that class. When I click my 1st button that has these lines of code in it, gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$iedoafjkjst1cmk11d5tgldi' of undefined` - similar error to `TestUtils.Simulate.click(node);` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752434/mocking-file-input-in-react-testutils

Comment: @rofrol I think my problem was in how I was getting `node`.  When I assigned an ID and used `const node = document.getElementById("myID")`, I got `TestUtils.Simulate.click(node);` to finally work.  I tried again using the code above that used `initEvent` and `dispatchEvent`, and it stopped giving me errors, but it didn't work, either - nothing happened.  React version 15.3.1.  I dunno.

Comment: React handles events at the document level, and that's the root cause for why your answer works.

So you don't have to switch to the deprecated `initEvent` syntax - just adding `{bubbles: true}` as the second parameter of the Event constructor in the original code should work.

Comment: @JamesPearce Thanks. Can you edit the answer to add new approach?

Answer (score 3):

I created a small version of the https://github.com/vitalyq/react-trigger-change only for the input element.

No external dependencies, copypaste and it will work.

Works for React 16.9, checked with Safari (14), Chrome (87), and Firefox (72).

```
const triggerInputChange = (node: HTMLInputElement, inputValue: string) => {
      const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(node, 'value');

      node.value = `${inputValue}#`;
      if (descriptor && descriptor.configurable) {
        delete node.value;
      }
      node.value = inputValue;

      const e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
      e.initEvent('change', true, false);
      node.dispatchEvent(e);

      if (descriptor) {
        Object.defineProperty(node, 'value', descriptor);
      }
};
```

Comment: how about `<input type='checkbox' />`, i replaced the `value` with 'checked' but doesn't work

Comment: This answer has a shorter version with less code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23892547/what-is-the-best-way-to-trigger-onchange-event-in-react-js/46012210#46012210

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to add `{ bubbles: true }` to the created event. For example

```
target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true }))
```