# React custom checkbox => trigger 'change' event

Tags: reactjs, dom-events, custom-controls

I made `a custom checkbox control` made from a regular `div`/`span`.

Because the `<input type='checkbox'.../>` cannot have children element, so I created the another one from a `div` with `role='checkbox'` and `aria-checked={isChecked}`.
Then i handled the mouse & keyboard event for toggling the check state.

The question is:
How to trigger `'change'` event? The code below doesn't work in react 16

```
refTarget?.current?.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true, cancelable: false }))
```

The another trick is calling the `props.onChange` directly.
It works but the event doesn't bubble to parent `<form onChange={(e) => console.log('changed!')}></form>`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to achieve this.

### 1. create all events dynamically.

`eventTarget.dispatchEvent` won't work in React. check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39065010/11218031) for alternative approach and more information on this.

### 2. Receive onChange events from the input

You can receive keep the real `input` element hidden by opacity, and make it span full width/height of your element. Then you only have to listen `onChange` on this `input`.

This is how [material-ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/next/packages/material-ui/src/internal/SwitchBase.js#L38) does it

example

```js
const { useCallback, useState, useRef } = React;

const MyCheckBox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { onChange, onBlur, onFocus, ...otherProps } = props;
  
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
  const handleFocus = useCallback((e) => {
    // do something,
    // like add some className for effects
    if (typeof onFocus === 'function')
      onFocus(e)
  }, [])
  const handleBlur = useCallback((e) => {
    // do something,
    // like remove some className for effects
    if (typeof onBlur === 'function')
      onBlur(e)
  }, [])
  
  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    setChecked(e.target.checked);
    if (typeof onChange=== 'function')
      onChange(e)
  }, []);
  
  return <div onFocus={handleFocus} onBlur={handleBlur} className="checkbox-root">
  {checked ? 'Checked' : 'Not checked'}
    <input onChange={handleChange} ref={ref} type="checkbox" className="checkbox-input" {...otherProps} />
  </div>
})

const App = (props) => {
 return <div>
 <MyCheckBox onChange={e => console.log('change', e.target.checked)} onFocus={e => console.log('focus')} onBlur={e => console.log('blur')} />
 </div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```css
.checkbox-root {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.checkbox-input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.hidden-input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: but layering a transparent real input causing the parent element lost focus. there are already a focus/blur indication on that element.

Comment: the custom event works if listening from vanilla js addEventListener, but doesn't work on React's onChange={ } . Works on react v15 but doesn't on v16

Comment: @HeyyyMarco updated the answer. dispatchEvent won't work in react. You can read the attached question for more info.