Trigger form onChange on input click
I'm creating my custom React  component with some extra features. I would like to keep it as close to the default browser behavior as possible. Whenever I change something in the form's input I would like the change event to bubble up to the form. Unfortunately, I can't make it work.
I've read that the "change" event is apparently some special even in React's synthetic event system. None of the proposed solutions worked for me as they were for older React versions.
To simplify my problem I created this demo and what I would like to do is to trigger the form.onChange from within input's onPointerDown or whatever other event handler. Of course I can't call the form.onChange directly as I'm not in the control of this part of the code. Everything should be done through events bubbling. Is it even possible in React? I've tested it in some of the popular UI libraries and so far none of them does that for non-native select components.
export function Demo() {
  return (
    <form
      onChange={(event) => {
        const form = event.currentTarget;
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(formData)));
      }}
    >
      <input
        name="name"
        onPointerDown={(event) => {
          const changeEvent = new Event("change", { bubbles: true });
          event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}


Did you try using flushSync?

import { flushSync } from 'react-dom'
<input
name="name"
onPointerDown={(event) => {
flushSync(() => {
const changeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true })
event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(changeEvent)
})
}}
/>

I've tried flushSync in multiple different ways but doesn't make any difference.

Not sure if it helps. But look for the concept of Event Delegation. https://www.dhiwise.com/post/how-to-effectively-manage-event-bubbling-in-your-react-applications

Event Delegation is not a solution here. It's not a problem where the event is being caught but it's not being triggered in the first place. There is nothing to catch

Solution 4 : Using Simulate in the Test utilities
App.js
import { Simulate } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <form
      onChange={(event) => {
        console.log(`Input Changed simulated : ${event.target.value}`);
      }}
      onClick={(event) => {
        console.log('Input Clicked bubbled up');
      }}
    >
      <input
        name="name"
        onClick={(e) => {
          Simulate.change(e.target.form, { target: { value: e.target.value } });
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

Test run:
Clicked on the input element after typing the text 'some test data'.
console log generated as:
// Input Changed simulated : some test data
// Input Clicked bubbled up

Observation:
The first log entry has been created here by the event simulation. The user has clicked on the input element, and the onClick event hander in the input element has the code to simulate the event into a input changed event in the form element. Please note that the reference e.target.form is a generic one, it does not hard code anything here.
The second log entry is the result of the default event bubbling.

You can't directly call onChange event of the form by dispatching it from an input.
The onChange event of the form will trigger on any form's inputs changes.
React optimizes event handling by tracking the value changes of form elements. Without actually changing the input's value, React might not recognize the event as a meaningful change, even if the event is dispatched.
I think this is reasonable, because what's the point of calling onChange on a form (from input's onPointerDown in your case) if the values of its inputs haven't changed?

It was just an example but you can imagine that there is the X button that clears the input so it is changing a value. You would want it to be propagated to the form.onChange

Using only native browser approaches, you can only reset the entire form using input with type reset. In any case you will have to use custom solution using react refs or something else if you want to manipulate particular inputs

This post has been made by referring to the document over here : Event Propagation. The below quote from there may brief the matter.

Event handlers will also catch events from any children your component
might have. We say that an event “bubbles” or “propagates” up the
tree: it starts with where the event happened, and then goes up the
tree.

Solution 3 By default, events "bubbles" or "propagates" up the tree.
The following sample code demoes the same.
App.js
export default function Demo() {
  return (
    <form
      onChange={(event) => {
        console.log('Input Changed bubbled up');
      }}
      onClick={(event) => {
        console.log('Input Clicked bubbled up');
      }}
    >
      <input
        name="name"
        onClick={(e) => {
          console.log(
            'Onclick event will not bubble up since it has been stopped here.'
          );
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

Test runs
On clicking the input element in the browser
console log generated:
// Onclick event will not bubble up since it has been stopped here.

On typing the word "some thing" in the input element
log generated:
// Input Changed bubbled up (5 times the same message has been logged)


That doesn't solve the problem because I want the click even to generate the change event. I'm fully aware of the event propagation concept. Basically, I want to trigger the onChange event that will get captured in the Form.onChange

creating a Synthetic event is all about it. The following two docs talk about it. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/26991
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065010/why-react-event-handler-is-not-called-on-dispatchevent

Please see the solution 4 posted separately.

Solution 1 : Add events to form on need basis.
The following code shows the same.
The coding highlights:
a. A ref object is used to get access to the form object.
b. The handler addEventToForm will add events to the form object.
c. The handler listenerForAllFormEvents is the same  handler will listen to all events added.
App.js
import { useRef } from 'react';

export default function Demo() {
  const refForm = useRef();

  function listenerForAllFormEvents(event) {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(formData)));
  }

  function addEventToForm(event) {
    const eventName = event._reactName.substr(2).toLowerCase();
    refForm.current.addEventListener(eventName, listenerForAllFormEvents);
  }

  return (
    <form ref={refForm}>
      <input
        name="name"
        onPointerDown={addEventToForm}
        onChange={addEventToForm}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

Test run
// Events vs.                            Console log generated:
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// On pointing mouse on the input field  [["name",""]]
// On pressing tab from the field
// after typing the text 'good name'     [["name","good name"]]


As I said in my question, I don't have access to the form. I don't control how someone will use the component

Sorry, My mistake.

Solution 2 : Using "capture children events" handler in form object
Please see the sample code below.
The following handler formEventCapture in form object will capture all events of types - click and change in its children components.
App.js
export default function Demo() {

  function formEventCapture(event) {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(formData)));
  }

  return (
    <form onClickCapture={formEventCapture} onChangeCapture={formEventCapture}>
      <input name="name" />
    </form>
  );
}

Test run
// Events vs.                            Console log generated:
// ------------------------------------------------------------
// On pointing mouse on the input field  [["name",""]]
// On typing the text 'good name'     
// [["name","g"]]
// [["name","go"]]
// [["name","goo"]]
// [["name","good"]]
// [["name","good "]]
// [["name","good n"]]
// [["name","good na"]]
// [["name","good nam"]]
// [["name","good name"]]


Please read my question - I don't have access to the form.

Sorry, My mistake.

Kindly clarify a point : All events in the children objects are automatically bubbled up. The exception is when a child has opted to stopPropagation. Therefore kindly clarify your objective once again may be with another example. Sorry if I am not able to get you.

Ok, so I have an  in React component and let's say that on the component render I want to trigger the change even on the input that will bubble up to the wrapping  element. The form might be there or not - I don't know. That's it. It looks like it's React's limitation.

I am really sorry if I am wrong in the following comment of mine. To me, what you have clarified is there by default. Please see my another answer - Solution -3, this is posted as an answer just to communicate to you by some codes as we are not able to post codes here in the comments.
